# How to exclude all functions from a library/file from CPU profile for JavaScript in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling

I use the developer tools of Google Chrome v54.0.2840.99 and created a CPU profile of my JavaScript application.

I would like to exclude some third party libraries from the profile (breeze and knockout) to focus on my own functions.

I am able to exclude single functions from the profile but it would be more comfortable if I could exclude all functions from specific libraries/files.

How can I do so? If this is not possible, is there a better profiling tool that provides that feature?

(I am able to focus on one of my own functions ... after I found it ... e.g. defaultInitializer in modelBuilder.js and filter out all others. That kind of helps but I would prefer to start with a filtered total overview that already only includes "my functions".)

**Edit**

Some old related questions I just found:

[What is the best way to profile javascript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)

[How can I ignore libraries like jQuery when profiling JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384993/how-can-i-ignore-libraries-like-jquery-when-profiling-javascript/8492537)

Some links to profiling documentation:

- Chrome profiling: 
  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution
- Chrome console profiling:
  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#profile
- Firefox profiling:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Call_Tree
- Firefox console profiling:
  https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.profile

[image]

Comment: Have you found the answer?